# Facebook offline_access removal... Will some Android users need to login every 60 days?

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, facebook-android-sdk

I received an email from Facebook saying offline access will no longer be available as of May 1, 2012.

It seems to me that, all ***new*** users of my Android app, ***unless the user has the Facebook for Android app installed*** on their device, will need to relogin every 60 days.

***Am I correct?***

Relevant links

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/329021273822477?browse=search_4f757888330df1200687453

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#extend_token

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

Comment: are you developing any application on facebook just need the relevant information. This site for Techincall Questions and answers

Comment: I have an Android app that uses the Facebook for Android SDK to update the users wall.  It previously used the offline_access permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you use the "offline_access" to begin with?
From what you described it does not seem like you need it at all.

The facebook android sdk provided you with the [SSO](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#enablesso) which removes the need to login to facebook every time, if the user has the facebook application installed on his android.
Then, you can use the sdk [Dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/) or [api requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/request/) (even in [async](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest/)) to post on the users wall.
Since you are using the sdk it should already take care of the authentication process for you and will (if the user granted your facebook app the right permissions) have a valid access token that it will be using.

More than that, not all access tokens are valid for 60 days, only those created by a [server-side flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) or if you use the new end point facebook provided for those who used the "offline_access" permission. To read more about that check the [Removal of offline_access Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) doc.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.  I know it should work OK if the user has the official Facebook app on their phone but it seems strange to need to rely on that.  In the Removal of offline_access permission document, under the heading "Client-side OAuth and Extending Access_Token Expiration Time through New Endpoint" there is code to extend the token.  Unfortunately I have no idea if that is meant to be integrated into an Android app... any help appreciated

Comment: The sdk takes care of the option that the user does not have the fb app installed on his device, in such case it (the sdk) will open the user login dialog, and then the app login dialog (if the user hasn't approved it yet). That means that when the *authorize* call ends you should have a valid access token. I'm not sure if the new endpoint is meant to be used from an android device, but in general I would suggest you to try to avoid relying on old tokens.

Comment: So it seems that for users without the official Facebook app would be required to login again when that token had expired (?)  From my initial experiments it does seem to be 60 days.

Comment: How are you posting to the users' wall? Do you ask for the "publish_stream" permission and publish yourself or do you open a fb dialog and let the user publish?

Comment: I use the publish stream permission.

Comment: Well, in that case you will need to have the user login every time the access token is no longer valid. Though I think that in most cases it wiser to use the dialog to let the user publish to the wall.

Comment: Unfortunarely that is what i thought :-(